# How to make a div disappear on submit with a transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a simple todo app and I would like my div where I display some message beforehand to disappear with a transition when user submits their todo wish.

I can make the transition and make the div disappear by adding a new class:

```
.todo-hint-close{
  transform: translateY(500px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}
```

but this just makes it invisible and still occupies a place in my page. Whenever user submits anything the new items come after the div and it looks ugly. Instead I would like to use `display:none` but then I can't use my transitions. Any suggestion on how to come around with this problem?

Sorry for inconvenience here is what I have right now: https://codepen.io/eminaydin/pen/vYNKGoz

Comment: on click set a timer for 500ms and put the `display: none;` property to the style of the div. simple enough ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't thought of this way. Implemented this right now but now the transition is not smooth. I have transition on moving the div outside and then  when timer is done it suddenly disappears. So not really what I want to achieve.

Comment: show me your code so that i can test

Comment: Check the initial code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/casa90/pen/LYpZZjJ

I suggest u to use animated.css for animation.There are several animation types.
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/
 Easy to use. Just add and remove class to use

when u click submit make disappear with

```
 $('#yourElement').removeClass().addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
```

when u make appair after submit finish use

```
 $('#yourElement').removeClass().addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
```

```js
$('#doit').click(function(){
   
    $('#yourElement').removeClass().addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
});

$('#pulse').click(function(){
     $('#yourElement').removeClass().addClass('animated bounceInLeft');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="yourElement">Hello, world!</div>
<br />
<button id="doit">do it</button>
<button id="pulse">pulse</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I was actually searching for this website for a long time. I've seen it some time ago but totaly lost its trace. Thanks for reminding me again. I've tried to use it but still not the effect I want. check the link please: https://codepen.io/eminaydin/pen/vYNKGoz

Comment: Now I get another checkbox up on my custom checkbox. The functionality I wanted is there but need to sort this problem.

Comment: U just take css classes I added to your code. I added class which change display of it. If u use visivility it occupies its place if u use dipslay it doesn’t

Comment: Take with your working demo https://codepen.io/casa90/pen/LYpZZjJ